# GWT: Showing a String list in DataGrid

Tags: gwt

i got a Presenter that is supposed to present a popup window what contains a DataGrip to show log file entries from a String list. I try to set the appropriate settings, but the number of log file lines that are displayed do not match the String list. I tried to enhance the data assignment, resulting in the Presenter not being shown any more.
Could you please give me a hint what i am doing wrong?

The parts of my presenter related to the DataGrid are:

```
// Create a list data provider.
final ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();


public interface MyView extends PopupView, HasUiHandlers<DeviceLogfileUiHandlers> {
    DataGrid<String> getDataGrid();

}

@Inject
DeviceLogfilePresenterWidget(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view) {
    super(eventBus, view);
    getView().setUiHandlers(this);

}

protected void onBind() {
    super.onBind();
    // Add the cellList to the dataProvider.
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(getView().getDataGrid());


    TextColumn<String> stringColumn = new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String s) {
          return s;
        }
      };
    getView().getDataGrid().addColumn(stringColumn);


}

@Override
protected void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();

}


public void setDeviceLog(List<String> logEntries) {
    getView().getDataGrid().setRowData(0, logEntries);
//These entries make the presenter not show up any more:
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(getView().getDataGrid());
    dataProvider.setList(logEntries);
    getView().getDataGrid().setRowCount(logEntries.size(), true);
    getView().getDataGrid().setVisibleRange(0, logEntries.size());
    getView().getDataGrid().setPageSize(logEntries.size());
    getView().getDataGrid().redraw();

}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the page size of the DataGrid?

Comment: Its there: getView().getDataGrid().setPageSize(logEntries.size());

Comment: Definitely need some coffee..completely missed the scrollbar and the last block of code...